# WM_PAINT while waiting for server response

Tags: winapi, com

It seems to me, WM_PAINT messages are send to a window while a thread with this window is waiting for a synchronous response of the COM server. The message appears after a while, or when other actions of user appear. I would like to change background color of the window in this case, but how can I find out, if WM_PAINT is sent as a result of blocking COM server, and not just send in other cases?

I tried to expect a flag while painting, maybe in PAINTSTRUCT, but there I found anything. I need another API call to check this condition.

Comment: You can not obtain why `WM_PAINT` is sent using `WPARAM` or `LPARAM` - [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-paint) is described when `WM_PAINT` is sent.

Comment: First up, `WM_PAINT` is never sent to a window. It is generated, on demand, whenever there aren't any higher-priority messages queued up (such as mouse or keyboard input). As far as determining the why a `WM_PAINT` message is generated, there is no API for that. After all, there might not be a *single* reason for this message, since multiple window region invalidations might get coalesced into a single `WM_PAINT` message. You'll have to solve your problem some other way.

Comment: @IvanVenkov this is not exactly true. Depends from - what transport used for call com server. If this is alpc - of course will be no messages during wait. But if windows messages used as transport - we can receive messages during wait on response

Comment: Simply set in variable , before call server to true, and after call - set it to false. In paint message check this variable

Comment: @IvanVenkov See [When can a thread receive window messages?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040608-00/?p=38983).

Comment: A synchronous (blocking) COM server call is not allowed to block, that's illegal for an STA thread.  So the COM runtime does something about it, it runs a message loop while waiting for the response.  Underlying call is [MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-msgwaitformultipleobjects).  This call dispatches a subset of messages, WM_PAINT is one of them.  So the UI doesn't freeze while waiting for the response.  The only kind of messages you don't get are user input notifications.  Best to not make that a problem.

Comment: Hm, as far as I remember, in some situations you can get a grayed window when a blocking server call is made, and further actions of the user occur. So there is an action of the system. I agree to the internal waiting message loop with MsgWaitForMultipleObjects. Might be DWM is handling this grayed window but I see WM_PAINTS arriving. Is there a possibility to dispatch a flag set by MsgWaitForMultipleObjects, when it is in waiting mode? It would be great to check in WM_PAINT message for the reason of the call.

Comment: Problem for me is a blocking event handler, when the blocking server call is called out of an event procedure, and the WM_PAINT is again trying to raise another event. This is a terrible situation in Owner Drawing of the grid (there you have the DrawCell event for Owner Drawing)

Comment: You can update background color in the next `WM_PAINT` after the COM server sets one flag to the client application.